# how to set the data object in a vue-resource such that it won't error in console

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I am learning Vue this weekend so a very simple question.

I'm trying to convert some jQuery to using Vue with vue-resource. I am getting back data for a location with items. The problem I'm having is that whenever I load this object, I get an error saying the location is null (which is what I set it to be in `data`. What is the proper way to do this? Should I have a guard statement to prevent it rendering through items? If it was an array of locations, I could set to an empty array but for a single object, it seems like should be null. How best to have an empty data object that is filled via an async call?

```
const Location = {
    data(){
       return {location: null }
    },
     template: `<div>{{location.name}}
                   <div v-for="item in location.items">
                     <div>{{item.id}}</div>
                   </div>
                </div>`,
        created(){
          this.fetchData();
       },
       methods: {  fetchData(){
         this.$http.get('/arc/api/v1/site_admin/locations/' + this.$route.params.id + '/dashboard').then((response) => {
           console.log(response.data);
           this.location = response.data.location
        }).catch( error => { console.log(error); });
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're receiving is due to your template attempting to render with `location` set to `null` as you've noted. In these instances, you should use `v-if` to tell the part of the template that deals with a populated `location` that it should not render unless one is set:

```
<div v-if="location">
  {{ location.name }}

  <div v-for="item in location.items">
    <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: `vue-resource` has been [officially marked as no longer undergoing active development](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4). Though there are no issues with using it, you should consider using an alternative AJAX library like axios instead, to future-proof your journey with Vue.

Comment: thx for advice, was seeing more how-to's with vue-resource but will switch to axios. Really appreciate the help